# var in function's parameter not working

Tags: jquery, parameters, var

I added a var in the parameter in the function:

```
//
msg = "test message";
date = "02-28-2013";
cal.setData({ date : msg});
//
//this can't work
```

However, the following one works well

```
//
msg = "test message";
cal.setData({ "02-28-2013" : msg});
//
```

but I need to use the one containing **var**. 
How can I make it work?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var param = {}
param[ date ] = msg;
cal.setData( param );
```

In order to set a variable as the property name for an object, you have to use the bracket notation. To do so, first create an empty object, then add the dynamic property like seen above.

In your first example, the object, that is passed to the function, contains a property named `date` and not a property with the name of the value of the variable `date`.